# how to load uitableview after load data from json global function on objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

In my iOS Project I want to generate a table with data from a json secured url , i did the request url from global function in my project like this "+(Shared *)" , the problem is that the table is created empty data before the data is loaded in first cells appear on screen !

How can I generate the table after the data is loaded?
 -for notice:the first cells appear on screen the data be empty 
after scrolling down to disappear cells the data loaded correctly on other disappear cells, also if i go to another view controller in my project and return back to my table view the data loaded correctly , how can i  solve this problem .enter image description here

Comment: Show your code. Requests should be done asynchronously. It's up to you to reload the tableView once you got the JSON, and show a "loading" screen meanwhile.

Comment: Can you show your code

Answer (score 0):

are you using table view for the table mentioned above? if so, did you call [tableView reloadData] after json data is loaded?

```html
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"htttP://www.google.com"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:Nil];

[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
  {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
          if(!error)
          {
              NSError *error;
              NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
              NSLog(@"json - %@", json);
              block(json, error,httpResponse.statusCode);
          }
          else
          {
              block(nil, error,httpResponse.statusCode);
          }
      });
      
  }]resume];
```

Comment: yes , i did calling after json success , but when i track my could by debugger i saw that 
    [manager GET:strURL parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject){ } }
        failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {  }];
  in first checking didn't go either failure or success does not enter any one of them

Comment: refer to my comment above, perhaps you can see if anything returned within the JSON block?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your tableView Data source is getting the info from de NSMutableArray or NSArray (whatever you are using to store your JSON Data). when the JSON data is downloaded, store it in this array and call method [tableview reloadData].